# How to disable "Replacing Existing Files" features of windows installer?

Tags: windows, deployment, installation, windows-installer

Windows installer is replacing some files while starting the application. This is because these files versions are old as I replace them manually after installation. It's a configuration files.

I googled this issue and found that there's a feature in windows installer "Replacing Existing Files" that do this job based on file version.

**Do anyone know how to disable this feature?**

Answer (score 2):

Repair is a normal feature of Windows Installer and you can't disable it. Windows keeps a record of the file versions that were actually installed and if it finds that they are wrong, then there are triggers that will cause their replacement. That includes right-clicking the MSI file and choosing repair, or doing a repair from Programs/Features, as well as some automatic entry points. The official way to replace just some files is with a Windows Installer mechanism such as a patch or an update/upgrade of some kind.

You don't say which tool you're using to build your MSI files, but the supported way to tell Windows you don't want it to manage your installed files is to use a null component id:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

and see the ComponentId description. That means you'll also need to remove them manually at uninstall time. Either you manage them or Windows Installer manages them. Or use a non-MSI setup to completely avoid the issue.